# Laravel and VueJS, access Vue instance.

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I want to change a data property and run a method on my Vue instance within Laravel. However due to using webpack and laravel I can't seem to access the instance how I would expect to:

So `window.app` doesn't appear to be the correct instance of my Vue class.

Below is the Blade View i'm loading, as you can see I append a script tag to my main `layout.blade.php`, simply trying to change the Vue instance data property, and run a method.

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        app.unsaved = true;
        app.triggerEvent(null, 'models', null);
    </script>
@endpush
```

Below is part of my `app.js` (resources/assets/js/app.js):

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'models-select': ModelsSelect
    },
    data: {
        showModel: false,
        unsaved: false
    },
    mounted: function() {

        let _self = this;

        (function() {

            document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select").forEach(function(e) {
                e.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    _self.unsaved = true;
                    e.classList.add('is-changed');
                });
            });

            function unloadPage(){
                if (_self.unsaved) return 'You appear to have un-saved changes!';
            }

            window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;

        })();

    },
    methods: {

        triggerEvent: function(event, target, property)
        {
            app.$refs[target].update(event, property);
        }
```

As you can see i'd expect to manipulate the Vue instance through the global **app** variable I have defined within the `app.js`. However this doesn't appear to be the case.

I get the following error when running the `triggerEvent` method:

> app.triggerEvent is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `app.js` file, change `const app = new Vue({` to `window.app = new Vue({`.

Then within your `<script>` tags, change it to this.

```
<script>
    window.app.unsaved = true;
    window.app.triggerEvent(null, 'models', null);
</script>
```

Comment: I thought that by defining the const in the global space it would get assigned to the window. Thanks, this works.

Comment: No problem. When Webpack transpiles it down, it will just change it from a `const` to a `var` - so it won't be available on the `window` object.